# RabbitMQ "node not running"

Tags: rabbitmq

[image]

I have set up a RabbitMQ cluster on a few workstations on the network. I'm viewing the cluster through the admin UI on my own workstation and seeing that neither of the other nodes are running.

I've checked the status of these nodes via rabbitmqctl and the Windows service is definitely started. Can someone tell me why the admin UI is showing this? Also, I set up a policy to mirror queues to all nodes in the cluster so how can I check to see that this is the case?

Comment: Configs, logs, please? Not enough information, am afraid.

Answer (score 1):

You can check cluster availability from your management node using `rabbitmqctl cluster_status` command.
If cluster_status will tell you that nodes are not running while rabbitmqctl on this nodes is reporting it's running - this can be caused by network partition.
Network partition can be caused by network or firewall configuration. You will have to check if you can access hostnames (part of nodename after @) and that `epmd` ports on all of your nodes are not blacklisted by firewall.
More information can be found in [Rabbitmq clustering guide](https://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html)